# Why is the launching of JUnit tests unexpectedly failing?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm trying to get unit tests running for an OS project I imported from github using the Spring Source eclipse IDE. On the import from github there is no project, so used the wizard to create a new project.

If I run maven builds or maven tests, everything works fine. However, if I try to run a single unit test file from inside Eclipse using cmd-opt-x t I get the following error:

> Launching of JUnit tests unexpectedly failed. Check log for details.
>
> Reason:
> (ProjectName) does not exist

I've searched for similar errors but haven't found anything. What is going on here?

---

The URL of the github account is: `git://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce.git`

Comment: Do you try to run the single test in maven or eclipse? Have you checked the log, Views->Error Log?

Comment: You may also try to debug it with step-by-step if you have attached sources. May be this will help reveal the problem

Comment: The URL of the github project would be useful here...

Comment: made edits to clarify question and give url of github project.

Comment: whats in your eclipse .project and .classpath files? sounds like the prohects isn't correctly setup in eclipse